# Getting error on TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm getting this error. Kindly note `splits` is an array with values.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

on

```js
var products = splits.reduce((accu, curr) => {
  if (accu[curr[0]] === null) {
    accu[curr[0]] = [];
  }
  accu[curr[0]].push(curr[1]);
  return accu;
}, {});

var result = Object.keys(products).map(key => `${key} - ${products[key].join(', ')}.`).join(' ');
```

Appreciate anyone helps to fix the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null === undefined` is `false` in Javascript.

```js
console.log(null === undefined);
```

So the condition `accu[curr[0]] === null` will return `false` though the `accu[curr[0]]` is `undefined`. Instead you could use the negation (`!`) to check if the variable is defined

```js
console.log(!null);
console.log(!undefined);
```

Try the following

```js
let products = splits.reduce((accu, curr) => {
  if (!accu[curr[0]]) {
    accu[curr[0]] = [];
  }
  accu[curr[0]].push(curr[1]);
  return accu;
}, {});
```

Comment: Changed to (!!accu[curr[0]]) but still getting the same error. Error is in the line with the code "push"

Comment: It must be `(!accu[curr[0]])`. I've adjusted the answer. Please see if it works now.